# Android Kotlin - retrofit2 Upload INPUTSTREAM with some POST parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Since it's impossible to do it with loopj on older Android APIs I wasted TWO DAYS looking at all the alternatives and retrofit2 (which looks like complete garbage just like all other loopj "alternatives") is my last hope before I increase minSdkVersion to 26 because I'm getting sick and tired of it..

All I need is simply upload a InputStream as FILE along with couple POST parameters.

In godly loopj you do it like that:

```
val params = RequestParams()
params.put("userid", prefs!!.getLong("userid", 0))
params.put("nickname", prefs!!.getString("nickname", ""))
params.put("file", finalInputSteam)
```

But in retrofit2 apparanetly you need to do all kind of extra bs for this simple task.

This is the abomination I have so far:

```
    interface FileUploadService {
        @Multipart
        @POST("upload")
        fun upload(
            @Part("description") description: RequestBody?,
            @Part file: MultipartBody.Part?
        ): Call<ResponseBody?>?
    }
```

and

```
    val service: FileUploadService =
        ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService::class.java)

    // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    val file: File = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri)

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    val requestFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse(contentResolver.getType(fileUri)),
        file
    )

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    val body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile)

    // add another part within the multipart request
    val descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking"
    val description = RequestBody.create(
        MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString
    )

    // finally, execute the request
    val call = service.upload(description, body)
    call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?>() {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ResponseBody?>?,
            response: Response<ResponseBody?>?
        ) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success")
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<ResponseBody?>?,
            t: Throwable
        ) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.message)
        }
    })
```

Problem 1: `Unresolved reference: ServiceGenerator` WTH is this??

2: Where do I define the URL???

3: It says I need to download `aFileChooser` but I don't want users to upload their 100 Megapixel 50 Megabytes Images but have the either gif or in size reduced jpg or from png to jpg converted and in size reduced image inside `finalInputSteam`

Please help :( Editing this code isn't necessary, when somebody could give me a working a for humans understandable Kotlin code that shos how to send:

```
val params = RequestParams()
params.put("userid", prefs!!.getLong("userid", 0))
params.put("nickname", prefs!!.getString("nickname", ""))
params.put("file", finalInputSteam)
```

it would be more than enough

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-multipart-request-kt-java

Comment: This doesn't show how to upload INPUTSTREAM

Comment: That is not supported directly. OkHttp, like any well-written HTTP client, needs to be able to retry an operation. Unfortunately, in Java (and Kotlin/JVM by extension), you cannot reliably rewind an arbitrary `InputStream`. However, you can create your own `RequestBody` type. For example, [the second one on this OkHttp issue comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196) is the recipe for uploading the content identified by a `Uri`.

Comment: Omg all this is such a horrendous bs compared to web developement..